# Connect USB C / Thunderbolt 4 to USB A (input! for USB 3.0 Hub) using a normal USB C to USB A cable?

Tags: mac, usb-3, usb-c, thunderbolt, usb-hub

I have an old USB (A) 3.0 Hub [Aukey CB-H18](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/aukey-cb-h18-docking-stations-usb-hub-9033160), which I have been happily using with my [late 2013 15" macbook pro](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-15-dual-graphics-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html).

Now i updated to a new [2023 14" macbook pro m2](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-m2-max-12-core-cpu-30-core-gpu-14-2023-specs.html) and naively thought I can just use a [USB C to USB A cable](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0BG1GTGXN?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1&language=en_GB) to connect the same USB hub, but it does not seem to work.

Did I just get the wrong cable (i.e. Thunderbolt v.s. USB C?), or is this just not possible (i.e. protocol thing)?
I was also thinking that maybe the USB A input on the hub is kind of non-standard (should probably be a USB B) and maybe a problem.
Or is this a mac issue?

Comment: Looks like this is actually a USB-A to USB-C cable (not the other way around, as advertised). I doubt it has the electronics required to be usable both ways. // Also, your hub is an “illegal” USB device: USB-A cannot be on an upstream connector.

Comment: Ok, so you think I would need a true USB-C to USB-A cable, because they would not work bidirectionally (which makes sense to me). The problem is, as you stated, that USB-A on the "receiving" side is non-standard, so I am probably out of luck...

Comment: You can always continue using the A-A cable that came with the hub, in combination with an adapter.

Comment: That's actually a great hint, have not thought about an adapter. Not a big fan of adapters, tbh, but if the cable that I need does not exist, maybe thats a good solution. 
I might also look into making my own cable by soldering a USB-A connector to a USB-C to USB-B cable (instead of the USB-B connector). You think that could work? I guess I could measure the pinout from the A-A cable.